# Spark 3.1.1 and 3.1.2 failed register class with Kryo: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedBatch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We try to upgrade Spark version for our application from Spark version 2.4.0 to 3.1.2 version. I tried Spark version 3.0.1, 3.0.3, 3.1.1 and 3.1.2. Spark version 3.0.1 and 3.0.3 work fine, but for 3.1.1 and 3.1.2, I got the following SparkException. I cannot find the class (org.apache.spark.sql.**execution**.columnar.CachedBatch) from any spark package. But I do find another similar class (org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.CachedBatch) (without **execution** in the class path) in package spark-sql_2.12-3.1.2.jar. Please let me how to get rid of the following exception. Thanks!

The following is the stacktrace when run our application:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.$anonfun$newKryo$5(KryoSerializer.scala:173)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.withContextClassLoader(Utils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$$anon$1.create(KryoSerializer.scala:102)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.borrow(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$PoolWrapper.borrow(KryoSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.borrowKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.<init>(KryoSerializer.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serializeStream(KryoSerializer.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1509)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat.buildReader(TextFileFormat.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(FileFormat.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat.buildReaderWithPartitionValues$(FileFormat.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.TextBasedFileFormat.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(FileFormat.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceScanExec.scala:398)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.doExecute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.TextInputJsonDataSource$.inferFromDataset(JsonDataSource.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.TextInputJsonDataSource$.infer(JsonDataSource.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonDataSource.inferSchema(JsonDataSource.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat.inferSchema(JsonFileFormat.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$11(DataSource.scala:209)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:519)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:428)
    at com.modeln.revvy.calcengine.spark.CMnSparkModelGenerator.loadJsonEntity(CMnSparkModelGenerator.java:545)
    at com.modeln.revvy.calcengine.spark.CMnSparkModelGenerator.loadEntity(CMnSparkModelGenerator.java:316)
    at com.modeln.revvy.calcengine.spark.CMnSparkModelGenerator.loadEntityDataFrames(CMnSparkModelGenerator.java:196)
    at com.modeln.revvy.calcengine.spark.CMnSparkModelGenerator.generateAndRunSparkModel(CMnSparkModelGenerator.java:165)
    at com.modeln.revvy.calcengine.spark.CMnCalcEngineDriver.main(CMnCalcEngineDriver.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:732)
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedBatch**
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.$anonfun$newKryo$6(KryoSerializer.scala:164)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.$anonfun$newKryo$5(KryoSerializer.scala:163)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My question is how to resolve org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedBatch class not found exception. What library is missing from my class path? The exception only happen with Spark 3.1.1 and 3.1.2 versions for my application. Thanks for your help.